# VHDL Syntax error in IF-ELSE block of finite state machine

Tags: syntax, vhdl

```
IF (((SW(17) = '0') OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0'))) OR ((SW(17) = 1) AND (SW(16) = 0) AND (SW(14) = 1)) AND (tempCounter = 1)) THEN
           next_state <= STATE1;
           resetTempCounter <= '1';
        ELSE
           next_state <= STATE0;
        END IF;
```

The code above throws a syntax error. I have checked the brackets, and I don't think that's the problem. I initially broke up the long line and thought that was the problem but that wasn't. I should also probably inform you that the code is in a process statement and that is not the problem.

**Errors**:

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Lab4b.vhd(241) near text "AND";  expecting ")", or ","

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Lab4b.vhd(244) near text "ELSE";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement

I'm fairly new to VHDL programming so bear with me and I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me write your statement in a different way to show the problem:

```
A = ((SW(17) = '0') OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0')))
B = ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0') AND (SW(14) = '1'))
C = (tempCounter = '1')
```

you have now:

```
if A or B and C then
   ...
```

the **issue can be solved** by writing e.g.:

```
if (A or B) and C then
   ...
```

or

```
if A or (B and C) then
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `SW` is declared as a `bit_vector` or an `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, you've got your comparison operators wrong : remember that both `bit` and `STD_LOGIC` are really enumerated types consisting of values mimicking the "real" ones, and not integers (in which case `0` and `1` would make a valid choice).

Therefore, all that you need to do is add apostrophes around `0` and `1` in this case. Check if this works (also supposing that `tempCounter` is an `STD_LOGIC` or `bit` type signal) :

```
(((SW(17) = '0') OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0'))) OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0') AND (SW(14) = '1')) AND (tempCounter = '1'))
```

Comment: Not adding the single quotes was an error. However, it was one that I overlooked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the line and the problem is easier to spot...

```
IF (((SW(17) = '0') OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0'))) 
 OR ((SW(17) = 1) AND (SW(16) = 0) AND (SW(14) = 1))
 AND (tempCounter = 1)) THEN
```

In one place, `SW(17) = '0'` - this is a std_logic or bit value. correct.
In another,   `SW(17) = 1`   - this is an integer, ... not so much.

I believe that too many brackets deducts from clarity, I would reduce

```
(((SW(17) = '0') OR ((SW(17) = '1') AND (SW(16) = '0'))) 
 ... )
```

to

```
((SW(17) = '0' OR (SW(17) = '1' AND SW(16) = '0')) 
 ... )
```

to reduce confusion a little. Who knows, with a bit less clutter you might have spotted the simple typos yourself?

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thank you.